Tonconnect не работает отправка транзакции через мобильное приложение
Всем привет, пытаюсь добавить отправку транзакции через tonconnect/react-ui
На примере tonkeeper
Если привязывать кошелек через десктопное приложение то отправка транзакции работает корректно
Если привязать свой кошелек через мобильное приложение Ton keeper, то при попытке отправить транзакцию то кидает ошибку
TonComponent.jsx:35 Transaction error: 
Error: Bad request
    at SendTransactionParser.parseAndThrowError (@tonconnect_ui-react…?v=021f6157:4172:11)
    at TonConnect.<anonymous> (@tonconnect_ui-react…?v=021f6157:6244:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (@tonconnect_ui-react…?v=021f6157:3976:24)
handleClick  @  TonComponent.jsx:35

Мой код компонента
const TonComponent = observer(({ title }) => {
  const wallet = useTonWallet();
  const [tonConnectUI, setOptions] = useTonConnectUI();
  const { amount } = ModalStore;
  
  const transaction = {
    // validUntil: validUntil,
    messages: [
      {
        address: "UQCXWm9dAZD6bzyiPMLjTLSnfrk0nej38XmnZYVVm2exEmK3",
        amount: '500000', 
        // payload: UserStore.id
      }
    ]    
  }
  console.log('Transaction:', transaction);
  
  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      await tonConnectUI.sendTransaction(transaction);
      console.log('Transaction sent successfully');
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Transaction error:', err);
    }
  };
  
  return wallet ? (
    <Button variant={'contained'} color={'success'} onClick={handleClick}>
      {title}
    </Button>
  ) : (
    <TonConnectButton />
  );
});

export default TonComponent;

